# How to compare two LocalDate objects in Criteria API?

Tags: java, criteria, criteria-api

I want to compare two `LocalDate` objects in Criteria API but `cb.equal` is not working or I can't even use `cb.isTrue()`  as `LocalDate.equals()` returns `boolean` not `Boolean`. What is the correct way to compare these?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I don't have error but it is obvious that I can't compare so I asked suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to use Criteria API? If not, it's fairly simple, use the `LocalDate.compareTo(ChronoLocalDate other)` method. The result will be integer, negative if the date is less than the compared to, positive if it is greater than the compared to date.

You might also consider methods such as `LocalDate.isAfter` , `LocalDate.isBefore` etc.

Comment: yes I have to use Criteria API because I am writing this comparison in Specification